# Ethernet not showing up in available connections - Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, 15.04, internet, network-manager, ethernet

I thought this would be a standard issue but I can't seem to find the answer on the internet.

I have a Dell Inspiron 7527 with Kubuntu 15.04 installed, using the network-manager.
Unfortunately the Ethernet connection is never showing up in the network manager.

I tried adding a new wired connection with the network-manager but it didn't work.

On Windows (I run a dual-boot), Ethernet works perfectly, so the cable is not at fault here.

My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Running `sudo lshw -C Network` shows that my ethernet card is recognized:

```
~ sudo lshw -C Network             
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 73
   serial: fc:f8:ae:c2:06:64
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-25-generic firmware=25.17.12.0 ip=192.168.1.83 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:47 memory:e3500000-e3501fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
   logical name: eth0
   version: 12
   serial: e0:db:55:c2:ce:83
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:e3404000-e3404fff memory:e3400000-e3403fff
```

Running `sudo dhclient eth0` does nothing (it just hangs).

Here is the `ifconfig eth0` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:db:55:c2:ce:83  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I also tried `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` but nothing changed.

Hope it helps.
I can't seem to find a solution to this really annoying problem (my work needs me to have ethernet activated),.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with glitchy Realtek driver **r8169**.
Many reported that disabling **autonegotiation** helps.
You can turn it off by using the following command:

`sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off`

Comment: Thanks a lot!   
Unfortunately I get a `Cannot get device pause settings: Operation not supported` :(
Do you know why? :)

Comment: I ran `sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off`, now the connection works. You are my hero.